# Can range monitoring be done in the background?

Tags: ibeacon-android, altbeacon, eddystone

Based on the samples provided in the site http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html , we can use RegionBootstrap to perform background monitoring of regions.

Instead of launching an app, once a region is entered, I start ranging by binding the Application class as a consumer. However, after calling BeaconManager.bind, onBeaconServiceConnect() is not called.

Is this a limitation of the library or is there something I'm doing wrong for ranging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `RegionBootstrap` class, you don't need to make your Application class implement the `BeaconConsumer` interface, as the `RegionBootstrap` implementation handles that internally.  You simply make the Application class implement `BootstrapNotifier`.

You can see an example of this in the [samples](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html) page you mention under the **Starting an App in the Background** section.  Note that the example in that section does not explicitly call the `bind` method on `BeaconManager`, nor does the Application class implement `BeaconConsumer`.

**EDIT**: If you want to add background ranging, simply make the Application class implement `RangeNotifier`, then add the following to the `didEnterRegion` method:

```
beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);
try {
    beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
} catch (RemoteException e) {    }
```

Comment: Thank you @davidgyoung! I was more concerned, however, with ranging in the background. I understand that RegionBootstrap allows us to detect didEnterRegion and didExitRegion events. I was wondering if there is a way to get Range Notifications in the background as well, since this is where we can access the actual beacons inside the region.